# iBeacon + Parse + Swift. CLProximity

Tags: ibeacon

Need some help. I can store an ibeacon's Major Minor, UUID in Parse. But how can I story the CLProximity?

**Example:**
This works as I can easily convert string to Int which matches the major NSNumber type.

```
if clBeacon.major == beacon.objectForKey("major").integerValue
```

This does not work:
beacon is a `PFObject and "CLProximity"` is the Parse column of type String.

```
if beacon.objectForKey("CLProximity") as CLProximity (This doesn't work)
if beacon.objectForKey("CLProximity") as String (This doesn't work)
```

Any advice guys?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CLProximity) {
    CLProximityUnknown,
    CLProximityImmediate,
    CLProximityNear,
    CLProximityFar
} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

So, you could store `CLProximity` as `NSInteger`

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the int, but if what you want to store is some kind of human readable data, I suggest doing something like this:

```
extension CLProximity {
    var stringValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .unknown:
            return "unknown"
        case .immediate:
            return "immediate"
        case .near:
            return "near"
        case .far:
            return "far"
        }
    }
}
```

So you can just do:

```
print("Proximity: \(proximity.stringValue)")
```

Works for me.